# Launch Contacts Activity through Intent

Tags: android

I want to show device Contacts Activity in Android.I don't need list of contacts to show in my custom view.
Following the code make exception of unable to handle activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Did you add your class to manifest file?

Comment: I want to call mobile Contacts activity not custom acivity(Contacts activity is a system activity).so how you can find a class of Contacts activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `READ_CONTACT` permission in AndroidManifest.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 10011);
```

Comment: what should i do in onActivityResult?

Comment: Just like @Stanojkovic if you want to use the contact info you have selected.

Answer (score 2):

**1) Permissions**

Add a permission to read contacts data to your application manifest.

**2) Calling the Contact Picker**

Within your Activity, create an Intent that asks the system to find an Activity that can perform a PICK action from the items in the Contacts URI.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
```

Call startActivityForResult, passing in this Intent (and a request code integer, PICK_CONTACT in this example). This will cause Android to launch an Activity that's registered to support ACTION_PICK on the People.CONTENT_URI, then return to this Activity when the selection is made (or canceled).

```
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

**3) Listening for the Result**

Also in your Activity, override the onActivityResult method to listen for the return from the 'select a contact' Activity you launched in step 2. You should check that the returned request code matches the value you're expecting, and that the result code is RESULT_OK.

You can get the URI of the selected contact by calling getData() on the data Intent parameter. To get the name of the selected contact you need to use that URI to create a new query and extract the name from the returned cursor.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data); 
switch (reqCode) {
case (PICK_CONTACT) :
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
Uri contactData = data.getData();
Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
// TODO Whatever you want to do with the selected contact name. 
    }
}
break;
    }
}
```