# Open Contacts on device via icon tap flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Is it possible to open the contacts on a device from an icon tap in flutter? I am able to open the phone function using url_launcher's plugin.I have used the contacts plugin but we dont have a need to manage contacts from our application, we want to use the phones functionality for managing contacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using Flutter [platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) and android [Intent.ACTION_VIEW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994750/launch-contacts-activity-through-intent) intent.

For example in your `MainActivity` register new channel and launch Contacts activity:

```
MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            launchContactActivity()
        }

private fun launchContactActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.type = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
    }
```

And on flutter side:

```
void launchContacts() async {
    try {
      await platform.invokeMethod('launch');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to launch contacts: ${e.message}");
    }
    setState(() {
    });
  }
```

Please see [full example](https://github.com/pavelshackih/flutter_contacts). Hope this help.

Comment: I downloaded the example and got it running but I cant implement it in my app am I missign something? The error is on static const platform =
      const MethodChannel('flutter_contacts/launch_contacts');  , It says missing plugin implementation I looked for that file and import but dont see one in the example.

Comment: Please check android native part in activity: https://github.com/pavelshackih/flutter_contacts/blob/master/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flutter_contacts/MainActivity.kt

Comment: Im trying to mirror all the mainactivity dependencies but Im getting an error, is there something im missing with Kotlin? Ive never included it in my project:  error  "Cannot access built-in declaration 'kotlin.Unit'. Ensure that you have a dependency on the Kotlin standard library"

Comment: Yes. Android project should be configured with Kotlin in gradle files.

Comment: Im using VSCode on windows with android studio installed, will this work? It appears I have all the kotlin stuff in the gradle files that the example has

Comment: Yes. In Android Studio click Open Existing Android Studio Project then open <your_flutter_project_dir>/android/build.gradle. After sync it should work.

Comment: I tried that but got the same error, does it sync automatically or is there something I initiate?

Comment: Automatically when import project or you can force by pressing button Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Comment: I pulled it in and I get the same error. I didn’t see a sync button

Comment: Can you share reproducible part of your project? You can find sync button on main panel in Android Studio.

Comment: sure - its all in this post i made: let me know if im missing anything.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58921498/trying-to-implement-flutter-contacts-example-in-existing-flutter-app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202660/discussion-between-sam-cromer-and-aim).

Comment: There is a github library https://github.com/shmehdi01/intent_contact but only for android

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can't directly.

But you can fetch them and their info with [`contacts_service`](https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service) package.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: I’ve used that we don’t want to pull them in to dart just open the built in functionality

Comment: did someone get a solution yet?

Comment: any solution? still finding, please help