# Trying to implement flutter_contacts example in existing flutter app

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter, dart

I am trying to implement the flutter_contacts example that lives here: [flutter contacts](https://github.com/pavelshackih/flutter_contacts/blob/master/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flutter_contacts/MainActivity.kt) in my existing flutter application but im having issues with calling the kotlin method. I have mirrored the functionality completely as far as I can tell but when I call the launch contacts method it throws a missing plugin exception. Here is the error:

```
E/flutter (10095): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method launch on channel flutter_contacts/launch_contacts)
```

It works fine in the expmle application when i run it so im assuming i'm missing something.

Code for Mainactivity :

```
 package com.lightbridge.flutter_contacts

 import android.app.Activity
 import android.content.Intent
 import android.os.Bundle
 import android.provider.ContactsContract
 import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
 import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
 import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

 class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

var lastResult: MethodChannel.Result? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)

    MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
        lastResult = result
        launchContactActivity()
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            lastResult?.success("Done!")
        } else {
            lastResult?.error("Error", "Can't launch contacts", "")
        }
    }
}

private fun launchContactActivity() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    intent.type = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
}

companion object {
    private const val CHANNEL = "flutter_contacts/launch_contacts"
    private const val REQUEST_CODE = 42
}
 }
```

Dart code to launch

```
   void launchContacts() async {
   try {
    await platform.invokeMethod('launch');
   } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print("Failed to launch contacts: ${e.message}");
   }
  setState(() {
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the **setMethodCallHandler** you must write an if statement to check the method name and then execute it:

```
if (call.method == "launch")
     launchContactActivity()
```