# Open default contacts app from my app in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-intent

I am not asking to retrieve contacts data in my app, all I want is the user to be navigated to the default contacts app in the phone.

I have looked at many questions but all of them are about retrieving contacts data.

*Questions I have looked at:*

- [Open Contacts on device via icon tap flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58864197/open-contacts-on-device-via-icon-tap-flutter)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58864197/open-contacts-on-device-via-icon-tap-flutter

Comment: looked at it, was not helpful

Comment: Are you cannot open Contacts app with plugin?

Comment: what plugin are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, looked at the other answer.